# Replace a number input to alphabetical string in Codeignitor 4

Tags: php

I want to fetch input from view file and split that number into digits and replace each digit to a specific alphabet and then store it in database,

can anyone help me in this problem

```
$data = [
            'product_id' => $productId,
            'vendor_id' => $vendor_id,
            'purchase_date' => $purchase_date,
            'landing_price' => $landing_price,
            'retail_price' => $retail_price,
            'wholesale_price' => $wholesale_price,
            'current_price' => $current_price,
            'vendor_current_price' => $vendor_current_price,
            'freight' => $freight
        ];

$numbers = str_split($wholesale_price);


$replaceNumbers = [
            1 => 'S',
            2 => 'H',
            3 => 'O',
            4 => 'N',
            5 => 'E',
            6 => 'L',
            7 => 'A',
            8 => 'P',
            9 => 'U',
            0 => 'R'
];
$replace = str_replace($numbers, $replaceNumbers, $numbers);

$JoinReplacedWord = join($replace);
var_dump($numbers, $replace, $JoinReplacedWord);
die;
```

but i am not getting the number replaced i am getting the array replaced to alphabet

result -

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "4" 
    [2]=> string(1) "5" 
    [3]=> string(1) "0" 
} 
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "S" 
    [1]=> string(1) "H" 
    [2]=> string(1) "O" 
    [3]=> string(1) "N" 
} 
string(4) "SHON"
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the help, but there is a small issue in it, if a digit in number is getting repeated then it is considering as single digit, –

Comment: Output - string(45) "replaced word - PAE & wholesale_price - 88775" –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_replace instead str_replace

```
    $wholesale_price = 98765;

    $numbers = array_flip(str_split($wholesale_price));

    $replaceNumbers = [
        1 => 'S',
        2 => 'H',
        3 => 'O',
        4 => 'N',
        5 => 'E',
        6 => 'L',
        7 => 'A',
        8 => 'P',
        9 => 'U',
        0 => 'R'
    ];
    $replace = array_slice(array_replace($numbers, $replaceNumbers), 0, count($numbers));

    $JoinReplacedWord = join($replace);
    var_dump($JoinReplacedWord);
    //you will see string(5) "UPALE"
    die;
```

EDIT : bug fix for repeated digit example 88775

```
$wholesale_price = 88775;

$numbers = str_split($wholesale_price);
//remove array_flip, because array flip will cause array just use last index when number have repeated digit 

$replaceNumbers = [
    1 => 'S',
    2 => 'H',
    3 => 'O',
    4 => 'N',
    5 => 'E',
    6 => 'L',
    7 => 'A',
    8 => 'P',
    9 => 'U',
    0 => 'R'
];

$string = "";
foreach($numbers as $val){
    $string .= $replaceNumbers[$val];
}

var_dump($string);
//you will see string(5) "PPAAE"
die;
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the help, but there is a small issue in it, if a digit in number is getting repeated then it is considering as single digit,

Comment: Output - string(45) "replaced word - PAE & wholesale_price - 88775"

Comment: sorry @shreerangamvinaykumar for late response, i just edit my answer,

Answer (score 1):

If you just define your `$replaceNumbers`  array slightly different your code will work

```
$data = [
    'product_id' => 1,
    'vendor_id' => 2,
    'purchase_date' => '2021-12-12',
    'landing_price' => 123.45,
    'retail_price' => 234.56,
    'wholesale_price' => 12345678.90,
    'current_price' => 456.78,
    'vendor_current_price' => 567.89,
    'freight' => 111.22
];

$replaceNumbers = ['R', 'S', 'H', 'O', 'N', 'E', 'L', 'A', 'P', 'U'];

$numbers = str_split($data['wholesale_price']);

$replace = str_replace($numbers, $replaceNumbers, $numbers);

$JoinReplacedWord = join($replace);
var_dump($numbers, $replace, $JoinReplacedWord);
```

RESULT

```
RSHONELAPU
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to dig into this. According to your description, your code does exactly what you want it to do. It splits up `$data['wholesale_price']` and has each character replaced as defined by `$replaceNumbers`. According to your output, your input number was '1450'.

Do you mean by "i am not getting the number replaced" that `$data` is not refreshed? Then simply add `$data['wholesale_price'] = $JoinReplacedWord;`.